# gparted - Project web is currently offline

Tags: gparted

I can't install http://gparted.org/, as it is now. From the website I read:
`Project web is currently offline pending the final migration of its data to our new datacenter.`. Since I need it now and it has been offline for 1 day already, could you suggest an alternative way to install it? I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: `sudo apt install gparted`

Comment: What do you need from gparted.org ? Gparted is already in the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Oh yes. I was trying `sudo apt-get install gparted`. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because author himself said he was just looking for the apt-get command line.

Comment: I found out apt install is different than apt-get install, and I did not know. It is unfair to say "I was just looking for" that command.  However I would close the question with the reason being that `gparted.org` is now available on line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the gparted ISO so you can burn a DVD: [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/).

If you only want gparted installed in your current system:

```
sudo apt install gparted
```